# C++: Using pointers with cin.getline()

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, cin

I have this program that isnt working.

```
char arr[200] ;
char *p = arr;
cout << "Enter the string and press ENTER: ";
cin.getline(*p,200);
```

The problem is probably because im using pointers with cin.getline().

My question is

Is it possible to use pointers in cin.getline?

And if yes. Then how?

And if no. Then why not , and how to get around that problem (especially passing a string to a function)?

Comment: Changing the question in this way makes the answers non-sensical. Please revert the change so the question and answers match. You can always add a subsection with the edits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you just got the syntax wrong.

```
cin.getline(p,200);
```

istream::getline expects a pointer, so there is no need to dereference it, as you did.

Answer (score 2):

```
cin.getline(*p,200);
```

`*p` is of the type `char`.  You are dereferencing a pointer to `char`, so you get a `char` back in turn.  You're not passing a pointer.  Just pass in `p`:

```
cin.getline(p, 200);
```